# presentModalViewController vs. pushViewController Animation Direction and Functionality in Popping/Dismissing

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller

Im ny app there are several UIViewControllers structured in a UINavigationController being pushed one after the other; once reaching the last one they are all "popped" back using popToRootViewControllerAnimated.

In terms of workability it's the best way I found so far.

BUT in terms of the way it looks I prefer to use (in this app) the presentModalViewController and dismissModalViewControllerAnimated to navigate through the different views.

Is there a way to change the animation direction for the Push and Pop functions?

OR

Is there a function similar to popToRootViewControllerAnimated but working as dismissModalViewControllerAnimated that dismisses all UIViewControllers on stack till it reaches the RootViewController?